# setup.py imports not working when building package

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging

I am trying to build a python package that uses relative imports within each module. When I run `tests.py`, which imports both `module1` and `module2` everything works fine, but when I run `setup.py` I get an error that `module2` cannot be found.

My directory looks like the following:

```
.
├── cool_package
│   ├── cool_package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── module1.py
│   │   ├── module2.py
│   │   └── tests.py
│   └── setup.py
│   └── setup.cfg
```

`tests.py` looks like this:

```
import module1
import module2

# tests
```

`module1.py` looks like this:

```
import module2

# functions
```

then `module2.py` just has its own functions and `__init.py__` imports a bunch of functions from `module1`. All of my configuration is in a `setup.cfg` file, so setup.py is gutted. It looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

I tried adding a combination of the following lines to `setup.py` and it did not help:

```
py_modules = ['cool_package.module1', 'cool_package.module2'],
package_dir = {'': 'cool_package'},
```

No matter what I do, the `import module2` line in `module1` gives an error saying that `module2` cannot be found, yet when I run `tests.py` I have no issues.

I have tried running `setup.py` from the inner `cool_package` directory, the outer directory. I've tried changing the import in `module1` to import specific functions instead of the whole module. No success.

I've tried changing the import to be `.module2`, `cool_package.module2`, then it wouldn't even find it when running `tests.py`.

I have tried using the `build` pip module as well to no avail.

I also tried adding this to my `setup.cfg` file, even though I don't think `setuptools` reads from that and it was probably pointless:

```
[options]
package_dir=
    =cool_package
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=cool_package
```

Any help would be appreciated on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: `import module2` is not relative import — it's absolute import. `import cool_package.module2` is also absolute import with full path. `import .module2` is relative import. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+absolute+relative+import

Comment: @phd I see. Why isn't it working in this case then?

Comment: Because in Python 3 either you use absolute import with full path or relative import. `import module2` is neither so it doesn't work. Python searches `module2` in `sys.path` and fails.

Comment: @phd If you have a solution then you can feel free to leave an answer and I will mark as accepted. I've tried relative imports like `from . import module2` or absolute imports like `import cool_package.module2` and those haven't worked either. When I change to those and run `tests.py` I either get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` or `no module named cool_package.module2` and when I run `setup.py` I get `no module named cool_package.0`

Comment: `py_modules = ['cool_package.module1', 'cool_package.module2'],` that I'm sure is wrong. You don't want to install them as modules, you want to install them as a package. Remove the line and also remove wrong line `package_dir = {'': 'cool_package'},`. Instead add `packages = ['cool_package'],`

Comment: @phd Just tried that. Think I've tried that too before. I just get the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'` error

Comment: There is no global `module2`. There is `cool_package.module2`.

Comment: @phd Then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cool_package.0'` when I change the import to `import cool_package.module2 as module2`

Comment: What is `cool_package.0`? Looks like a misspelling.

Comment: @phd That's the exact error it gives when I run `setup.py`

Comment: BTW The same mistakes in your `setup.cfg`: remove `package_dir=
    =cool_package`, remove `[options.packages.find]
where=cool_package`. It seems you confuse `src` layout with plain layout. Your development directory uses plain layout so all options related to `src` layout must be omitted/removed.

Comment: @phd Thank you for all of the help. The issue was a stupid small mistake in `setup.cfg` in the line that sets the version number. Very frustrating cryptic error and I appreciate you helping me through it.